# How do I receive the self in default?

Tags: python, discord.py

I receive the user as a parameter when instantiating the class, but I can't use it

```
class ModalRegisterUser(discord.ui.Modal, title='Registrar Pedido'):
  def __init__(self, user):
    super().__init__()
    self.user = user

  name = discord.ui.TextInput(
    default= self.user.name,
    label='Seu nome',
    style= discord.TextStyle.short,
    placeholder='Pucci',
    required=True,
    max_length=20
  )

  async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    print(self.name)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Você foi registrado!', ephemeral=True)

  async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error: Exception) -> None:
    if type(error) == PriceError:
      await interaction.response.send_message(error.args[0], ephemeral=True)
    else:
      await interaction.response.send_message("Oops, ocorreu algum erro...", ephemeral=True)

class RegisterUser(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
```

instantiating the class
|
V

```
  @app_commands.command(
    name="registrar_usuario",
    description="Registra seu perfil no code freelas!"
  ) 
  async def Registrar(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = requests.get(f'http://localhost:7777/{interaction.user.id}')
    await interaction.response.send_modal(ModalRegisterUser(user))
```

I expected to receive self.user.name in default

Comment: `name` is a class attribute, independent of any instance method. You want to define `self.name` inside `__init__`.

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive. Your `__init__` method ended the moment you dedented. Indent it to the same level as the rest of `__init__` and your problems will disappear.

Comment: It's not just a matter of indentation. If you define `name = ...` inside `__init__`, it's just a local variable that goes away when `__init__` returns, and `self.name` is still not available to `on_submit`.

Answer (score 0):

A workable approach would be to define a name class property that gets values from a hidden _name attribute field,  and sets a default value from self.user.name if _name is not specified.

```
class ModalRegisterUser(discord.ui.Modal, title="Registrar Pedido"):
    _name = discord.ui.TextInput(
        default=None,
        label="Seu nome",
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        placeholder="Pucci",
        required=True,
        max_length=20,
    )

    @property
    def name(self) -> discord.ui.TextInput:
        if self._name is None:
            self._name = (user:= getattr(self, "user", None) and user.name)

        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, val):
        if isinstance(val, str):
            self._name = val

    def __init__(self, user):
        super().__init__()
        self.user = user

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print(self.name)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Você foi registrado!", ephemeral=True)

    async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error: Exception) -> None:
        if type(error) == PriceError:
            await interaction.response.send_message(error.args[0], ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Oops, ocorreu algum erro...", ephemeral=True)
```